# Подстановка данных в форму Access

Tags: access, форма

Здравствуйте. В прошлый раз писал сюда и так хорошо помогли, сейчас вот новая головоломка над решением которой думаю уже не первый день и похоже, что этот сайт - последняя инстанция.

Я делаю БД в MS Access, где имею 3 таблицы:

Передачи(Код передачи, Название, Рейтинг, Стоимость минуты)
Реклама(Код рекламы, Код передачи, Код заказчика, Дата, Длительность в минутах)
Заказчики(Код заказчика, Название, Банковские реквизиты, Телефон, Контактное лицо)

Ясное дело, что дубли полей с кодами служат для удобства при создании смежных таблиц или запросов. Я наделал кнопочных форм, где отображены поля для добавления информации в эти самые таблицы. Но вот когда дело дошло до добавления рекламы, появилась маленькая неувязочка. Первые 2 поля как бы для ввода чисел, но писать туда(Коды заказчика и передачи) числа в ручную очень не удобно, ведь мало кто их будет помнить. Я пришёл к выводу о создании поля с подстановкой, но и там получилось что можно или вывести список с кодами заказчиков и передач (Что тоже не удобно, ибо не понятно какой код к какой передаче относится). Максимально удобным вариантом было бы: Создать на месте поля ввода список, в котором можно выбрать передачу (Из списка названий) или заказчика (Из списка фирм), а чтобы в таблицу Рекламы записался код выбранного элемента. Сам я с Access работаю второй раз в жизни. До этого часто работал с тандемом Php & MySQL, где такое дело делалось при помощи хтмл форм и отправляло в массив $_POST уже ключи от записей из списка. Наверняка и в Access есть что-то похожее, поэтому, я и обращаюсь к знатокам и гуру :) Если что, то у меня есть немного денег на WM и могу поблагодарить не только от всего сердца.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Там в аксесе еще проще чем вручную пичипи с мускулом - само все сделает. Там есть какое-то место такое, где можно таблицы вывести в виде квадратиков, а потом указать стрелочками связи между полями таблицы просто перетянув одно к другому, да потом еще и свойства связи задать - один к одному, один ко многим и т.д., которые на выходи превратятся в различные джониы - иннер, левый и т.д.. А потом, если сделаешь автоформу, то все такие поля превратятся в комбобоксы со значениями из таблицы.

Comment: Не совсем то что я хотел. Вы описываете конструктор запросов и предлогаете сделать запрос и на его результате форму. Только вот запрос и отдаст же в поле "Заказчик" нвазение его фирмы, и непонятно куда оно запишется (Если вообще запишется)

Comment: Хотелось бы уточнить, мы записываем в таблицу Реклама, так? Для полей Код передачи, Код заказчика мы выбираем из списка, так? Куда должно уйти название фирмы? Если в поле Код заказчика, то нет, там должно хранится только Код Заказчика, а остальные значения прикрепленного заказчика (Название, Банковские реквизиты, Телефон, Контактное лицо) можно легко "достать" средствами аксеса в отчетах или, например, сделать отдельный запрос, где это все будет отображаться через, например, какой-нибудь разделитель в одном поле. Или что я не так понял?

Comment: Да, в таблицу рекламы нужно записывать именно код заказчика и код передачи средством вот этой самой формы. Я хочу чтобы именно в форме добавления рекламы был список с названиями фирм заказчика, а при добавлении записи в таблицу шло в это поле именно айди заказчика, фирма которого была выбрана в выпадающем списка

Comment: Да, реально так оно и было :) А я дурень не мог понять то что же вы в ответе написали. Сейчас уже и книжек море перебрал и примеры посмотрел, а в итоге оказалось что этот метод вы мне и описали (Хоть и не в самом внятном виде :)). Всёравно спасибо